# Who logs the flight hours for airline pilots?

Tags: airline-operations, pilots, logging

Airline pilots' flight hours vary a lot depending on the airline, type of operation etc. Who actually does the job of logging their flight hours? Do the pilots do that themselves after each flight or there is a system that does it for them?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

At my outfit, both.

Pilots log their own hours in the logbooks and keep a rough mental track of hours flown to ensure compliance with Flight Time Limitation rules.

The airline will also log pilot hours to stay in accordance with FTL and compare rosters to actual hours flown. This also serves to create a legal record of who was flying the aircraft should that be required at a later date.

Many - including myself - use an electronic logbook that pulls the data from the airline, so no writing needs to be done.

Comment: I also use an electronic log book that pulls data directly from the airline. I suspect it is pretty common these days. My airline also maintains software that is used by by pilots to "check in" for work and will give a warning if the pilot is approaching recently limits.  ( eg. 3 TO and Landings in 90 days)

Comment: The pilot is responsible for logging (and tracking) his own time, and is personally responsible for managing his FTL. Most airlines cross-match this with OOOI data from ACARS regularly. I'm not sure how they track pilot-in-command time electronically though, as this is done verbally on the flight deck during flight. Does anyone know?